# ggplot2 - Axis Aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

It is possible in `ggplot2` to draw that second "axis" label correlating the percentage of values from X and Y.

[image]

**Edit:**

I have a data.frame with two vars, both related and in percentage. I want to show the evolution of V1 related to V2; for example, how much percentage of V2 do i need to get 20% of V1 (and vice-versa).

```
V1   V2
0    0
0.03 0.0005
0.10 0.0015
0.13 0.0020
....
1    1
```

Now my problem is how can i do that inner axis on X and Y, showing the relation between X and Y percentages.
Also how can I set ggplot to use (0,0) as the intercept of the x and y axis?

Comment: you could use `geom_rect` and `geom_text` to manually add these values. It would be great if you could provide extra details about the computed values, as it is not clear what are you showing on the inside "axis".

Comment: @daroczig: i edited the post with more information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build up this graph from layer to layer (with [geom_rect](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_rect.html) and [geom_text](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_text.html)) easily with ggplot2. Not a shiny solution, but you could get the picture by:

Generate some data to be used on the plot:

```
df <- data.frame(A=sort(runif(20)), B=sort(runif(20)))
df <- rbind(df, c(1,1))
```

Generate a modified version of the above data table to be plotted as "inner" axis (*note*: I only compute two parts by the median):

```
df_rect <- data.frame(xmin=c(0, median(df$A), -0.01, -0.01), xmax=c(median(df$A), 1, 0, 0), ymin=c(-0.01, -0.01, 0, median(df$B)), ymax=c(0, 0, median(df$B), 1), color=grey(c(0.7, 0.2)), alpha=c(0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4))
```

Generate something like that for the plotted text:

```
df_text <- data.frame(x=c(median(df$A)/2, median(df$A) + (1-median(df$A))/2, 0.05, 0.05), y=c(0.02, 0.02, median(df$B)/2, median(df$B) + (1-median(df$B))/2), label=rep('50%', 4))
```

And at last plot all:

```
ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) + geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_rect(data=df_rect, aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax, fill=color, alpha=alpha), inherit.aes = FALSE) + scale_fill_grey() +
    geom_text(data=df_text, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-0.01, 1), formatter='percent') + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.01, 1), formatter='percent') + opts(legend.position="none")
```

Where `geom_point` points the given values and `geom_line` connects all (as I saw in your example image). `geom_rect` with all parameters draws the grey "inner axis" and `geom_text` does the text part. You will have to play with the generated (input) data frames (in the   above example: `df_rext` and `df_text`) to get your desired data for these. `theme_bw`  stands for black and white theme and the two `scale_continous` option stands for setting the limits between 0 and 1 and also setting the percent `formatter`.

Which results in:
[image: sample plot]

I hope you will be able to customize and upgrade this little example to your needs!